# Alt text for a dropdown menu in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, alt

If I'm using Microsoft word and I leave my mouse to hover over the font dropdown menu, this popup appears:

[image: alt text for fonts]

It tells you the dropdown menu's name, what it's for and a shortcut to using it.

I have an Rshiny App with a dropdown menu, and I'd like to have a similar system to aid my users. How would I go about doing so?

Here is some code to show where I'm starting from:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fixedPage(
  # The alt-text would say "Choose from 3 options"
  fixedRow(selectInput("drop", "Features", choices = c(1,2,3))))

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```r
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
library(magrittr)
ui <- fixedPage(
    # The alt-text would say "Choose from 3 options"
    fixedRow(
        # since the dropdown will expand the element height, place on top or bottom is not ideal.
        column(
            6, 
            # use `bsPopover` for full customization
            selectInput("drop1", "Features", choices = c(1,2,3), width="50%") %>% 
                bsPopover("XX dropdown", "Choose from 3 options", "right")
        ),
        column(
            6, 
            # or the convenient function `bsPop` with preset colors
            selectInput("drop2", "Features", choices = c(1,2,3), width="50%") %>% 
                bsPop("XX dropdown", "Choose from 3 options", "left", status = "primary")
        )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh, that's neat and exactly what I think I need. Let me implement it and then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Marked as answer, but I wanted to comment specifically to mention that this only works in the browser. Not really an issue, but a caveat if I were to debug a system with this as a noob.

Comment: Never use Rstudio viewer for debugging. You would see a lot, not just this not work in the viewer.